# Can I have compression ratio less than 6.25% in this situation?

Tags: c++, compression

I have a text file which has long text made up of combinations of only two characters.

Is there any way I can compress them with compression ratio less than 6.25%.

I don't want to use any library or some function but
I want to have some formula or algorithm that does the work.
An idea is the best answer for my question.

P.S :- Actually I am trying to create one by my own but I don't know anything about this thing. whatever it is I am sitting with a pen+notebook and trying to do so all by myself.

Comment: Where does 6.25 come from? Is your file encoded in ucs-2?

Comment: You mean like represent one character by "0" and the other by "1", giving you 8x compression over an 8-bit representation?

Comment: @Nemo Cool! you figured my real situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compression ratio is directly determined by the content of your file. For example, a file that contains only `0`s `N` times can be compressed using `log_2(N)` bits (you just specify how many zeros it contains). Technically, the compression ratio is at best equal to the Shannon entropy of the source, since you may regard your file as containing symbols produced by some random source.

So, unless you know the structure of your file and can use some additional information, then it is impossible to guarantee a compression ratio below some threshold. If you have no idea about the structure and your file just contains random 0 and 1's, then there is no way of compressing it (the entropy is simply 1 in that case).

See e.g. [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Data_compression) for a bit more details. You should definitely read some introductory information theory, as otherwise re-inventing the wheel can be quite tedious.

Comment: re-inventing something is in my blood, when I am successful, I understand every bit of the thing **I** re-invented.BTW I will follow your advise when I am totally in need of it, thanks for that.

Comment: @MukulKumar don't underestimate Shannon, it took him a while ;)

Comment: @MukulKumar the best you can ever do is to achieve asymptotically the entropy of the source. That's what Shannon proved, and it is correct. So you cannot compress more. What you are doing is called "coding", and coming up with a code to achieve the maximum compression rate is extremely hard (in general is impossible, although there are good heuristics, see e.g. the zip algorithm which performs quite well). If you want to compress more than the theoretical limit, then you have to accept that you'll get imperfect decoding.

Comment: I was thinking that what if I could rename one combo of 4 chars like `aaaa` as `1` and so for every other possible combo...I pickup every 4-bytes and rename them to some other specific character how is that?

Comment: @MukulKumar: That will end up using 1 bit per character, which will result in the end file being 12.5% the size of the original file (it doesn't matter if you pick 1 char at a time or 4.) You can do this and then run a simple Huffman coder on top of it though to achieve better compression.

Comment: @vsoftco after thinking for a while about your 1st comment...looks like I am gonna need your advise real soon...But I am a tough gamer.. I am not gonna give up easily.....

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some other redundancy in your data, no.  The best you can do is 12.5%, i.e. 1/8th, since you can code each character as one bit.